# How can I create and position a container over a Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, position, xamarin, containers

In Xamarin, how can I create and position a container over a Layout?

Here is my Layout XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I create a container that has a TextView and a Button and then position this container where I want on top of the FrameLayout?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Relative Layout, you can arrange the elements where ever you want.
Check here [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How can I display the "thumbnail" LinearLayout on top of the FrameLayout? I cannot see the TextView or Button when the application is running?

Comment: problem was in framelayout android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" change it to
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: Now the line: android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail" hides the Google Map that I have in the FrameLayout. Only the LinearLayout is shown and the rest is black.

Comment: use android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail" instead of that.